# Integrating Ionic with Unity3D

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, ionic2, virtual-reality

I'm creating a mobile app using Ionic, but it also has some VR content developed using Unity3D.

For example, let's say the Ionic app has some pages to display information about cities. For every city, there's a link to a "VR Mode," which should load the respective Unity3D content.

The app should also have a general VR mode, where you can go there and see all content available to be experienced in VR.

I wonder what would be the best way to integrate both and do that.

1) Using Unity WebView would probably be the easiest way, but it would compromise the performance;

2) Maybe a way to call the normal Unity code from Ionic?;

3) Maybe create a different app just for the VR mode? In that case, I wonder if it's possible to link to specific parts in that app (e.g. If I click on the VR mode for New York, then I'd go to that specific VR content in the other app);

4) Maybe develop the entire app using Unity3D? Is it okay to develop normal content (that requires a lot of data) directly in Unity?

5) Maybe something else? :P

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: In my limited experience of Ionic(3 Months) and Unity3d (1.5 years). I only know 2 choices. Either make full application on Unity or link unity VR content webgl pages within html in ionic.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's what I'm thinking as well. Have you ever used Unity with webgl? How's the performance? Regarding features, there are limitations like WebVR? Because, in that sense, it might be even worth exploring more frameworks like A-Frame rather than doing the VR part in Unity. Then, I could create a different app entirely in Unity for a more advanced VR experience. Does it make sense?

Comment: why not you use threejs instead of Unity? https://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-vr-to-web-google-cardboard-three-js/ and also some outstanding work https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_lines

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually considering using A-Frame (https://aframe.io/), which is build upon threejs and it seems to have a good compatibility with different devices.